# How to create an object from an enumeration without all values in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enumeration called PaymentFrequency:

```
public enum PaymentFrequency {

  D("Daily"),
  W("Weekly"),
  M("Monthly"),
  Y("Yearly");

  private final String description;

  PaymentFrequency(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

And now if I do this in my bean:

```
private PaymentFrequency[] paymentPeriods = PaymentFrequency.values();

public PaymentFrequency[] getPaymentPeriods() {
  return paymentPeriods;
}

public void setPaymentPeriods(PaymentFrequency[] paymentPeriods) {
  this.paymentPeriods = paymentPeriods;
}
```

I will get all the values from my enumeration. How can I get only the values *W* and *M* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do

```
 private PaymentFrequency[] paymentPeriods = 
     new PaymentFrequency[] {PaymentFrequency.W, PaymentFrequency.M};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an array

```
static final PaymentFrequency[] WM = { W, M };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private PaymentFrequency[] paymentPeriods = new PaymentFrequency[] {PaymentFrequency.W, PaymentFrequency.M};
```

I'm not sure if this is your question...

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! This solved it:

        private PaymentFrequency[] paymentPeriods = {PaymentFrequency.W, PaymentFrequency.M};